# How to prevent plain ASP.NET project from publishing DLLs?

Tags: asp.net, publishing

I have an ASP.NET project which I'm basically using to edit static content - no server-side stuff. Is there any way I can prevent the Publish step from deploying the compiled DLL?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Web site project type in Visual Studio instead of Web Application (precompiled). This way you can copy individual files and they will be dynamically compiled by the ASP.NET at runtime. In this case you need to copy the `.aspx.cs` codebehind files as well but if you are editing only static files you should be OK with it.

Comment: Hmm, coming back to this idea, I don't see an option to create a web site. I go to File->New Website, but it only gives me Asp.Net options.

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk, yes, it gives you ASP.NET as there are two types of ASP.NET: web sites and web applications. What options did you expect?

Comment: ahh, my misunderstanding, then. But if it's ASP.NET, won't I have the same problem with useless assemblies?

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk, no because you are using a WebSite model. In this model you can directly deploy the source code (code behind) of your pages to the web server and it will be automatically compiled at runtime. When you use a WebApplication, this application needs to be precompiled (=> assemblies generated) before deploying.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of it to add a post build event on that specific project to delete the bin folder

del "$(SolutionDir)[main project name]\bin*.*"